# Using Gson to deserialize nested JSON having generic object type

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am currently using a basic JSON lib for my android application to extract JSON sent from our server. To improve performance i am thinking of moving to Gson.

Currently I am stuck with the deserialzation because of the following reason -

My classes -

```
public class GameResponse {

    public boolean failed = false;
    public Object jsonObject; // Type cast this object based on the class type passed in json string
}

public class GameBatchResponse {

    public GameResponse[] gameResponses;
}
```

Deserializing my jsonresponse -

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();

 GameBatchResponse response = gson.fromJson(jsonResponse, GameBatchResponse.class);
```

Now, how to tell Gson in which class it needs to type cast the JsonObject. Currently it is converting it into a LinkedTreeMap since it does not know which class it needs to type cast it to.

When i do `(MyClass)response.gameResponses[0].jsonObject` it gives class cast exception.

In current implementation, i used to pass @type in my Json string and will use that to create instance of MyClass. For e.g. - "@type":"com.mypackage.MyClass"

I am looking for a Gson implementation of the same logic, Where I am able to tell Gson the class type from the info appended in the JSON string at run time

Comment: To help you, it would be nice to have an example of the JSON you are trying to deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
public static Object createObjectFromJSON(String jsonString, Map<Class, AbstractAdapter>map,Class classType) {
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        if(map!=null) {
            for (Entry<Class, AbstractAdapter> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                builder.registerTypeAdapter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }
        builder.setPrettyPrinting();
        builder.serializeNulls();
        Gson  gsonExt = builder.create();
        return gsonExt.fromJson(jsonString, classType);
    }
```

You have to define your own AbstractAdapter classes

```
public class Adapter extends AbstractAdapter{

        @Override
        public AbstractSureCallDataFile deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
                JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException  {
            JsonObject jsonObject =  json.getAsJsonObject();
            JsonPrimitive prim = (JsonPrimitive) jsonObject.get(AbstractAdapter.CLASSNAME);
            String className = prim.getAsString();

            Class<?> klass = null;
            try {
                klass = Class.forName(className);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new JsonParseException(e.getMessage());
            }
            return context.deserialize(jsonObject.get(AbstractAdapter.INSTANCE), klass);
        }

        @Override
        public JsonElement serialize(Serializable src, Type typeOfSrc,
                JsonSerializationContext context) {

            JsonObject retValue = new JsonObject();
            String className = src.getClass().getCanonicalName();
            retValue.addProperty(AbstractAdapter.CLASSNAME, className);
            JsonElement elem = context.serialize(src);
            retValue.add(AbstractAdapter.INSTANCE, elem);
            return retValue;
        }

}
```

and call will be

```
Map<Class, AbstractAdapter> map=new HashMap<>();
                            map.put(Xyz.class, new Adapter());
                            Object obj= createObjectFromJSON(line, map, MainObjectClass.class);
```

Comment: there is no AbstractAdapter